# TableView Crashes when Trying to Insert

Tags: ios, uitableview

My app crashes when I try to insert a new entry. I received this error previously, and I was not able to fix it. Can anyone help?

Here is my error displayed in the console:

```
2013-09-14 15:41:00.370 Probation App[9919:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x31fe82a3 0x39ccc97f 0x31f33b75 0xd7b81 0x33eb228d 0x33f34f81 0x328f6277 0x31fbd5df 0x31fbd291 0x31fbbf01 0x31f2eebd 0x31f2ed49 0x35af62eb 0x33e44301 0x542fd 0x3a103b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

and here is my code:

```
#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource Methods

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if( nil == cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    if (indexPath.row <self.probationers.count)
    {
        Probationer *thisProbationer = [self.probationers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = thisProbationer.probationerName;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = thisProbationer.probationerID;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Add Probationer";
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView: (UITableView *)tv numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    NSInteger count = self.probationers.count;
    if(self.editing)
    {
        count = count +1;
    }

    return count;

    //return [self.probationers count];
}

//Deleting an Entry

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle) editing forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    if (editing == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [self.probationers removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    }
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate Methods

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Probationer *chosenProbationer = [self.probationers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ProbationerController *detailedViewController = [[ProbationerController alloc]init];
    detailedViewController.delegate = self;
    detailedViewController.currentProbationer = chosenProbationer;

    if (indexPath.row <self.probationers.count && !self.editing)
    {

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailedViewController animated:YES];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == self.probationers.count && self.editing)
    {

        AddProbationerController *addProbationer = [[AddProbationerController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:addProbationer animated:YES];
    }

    [tv deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    //selectedIndexPath = indexPath;



    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailedViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Why do you return count = count +1; when you're editing? I think that's your problem.

Comment: I thought it may have something to do with this... Do you know what I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Delete the if clause, and just return [self.probationers count].

Comment: Hmm, I did, and the following error occurs when I try to go into edit mode: reason: 'attempt to insert row 2 into section 0, but there are only 2 rows in section 0 after the update'.

Comment: You haven't shown any code for inserting, only deleting. Do you implement that code?

Comment: Well, at this point my app is only supposed to show a blank modal view when pushing the "insert" button. There is no insertion code yet. But the modal view is not displaying because the app crashes for the above reason.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37401/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-george-friday)

Answer (score 1):

The number of rows should always come from the data source (the bit you have commented out `//return [self.probationers count];`). Don't try to just add to the number. Add to the data source and then refresh the table view.

Comment: I uncommented the line, but it still is not working. The same error message appears. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Remove the `count = count + 1`. Where are you actually editing the `probationers`?

Comment: I removed it, but a different error appears, as soon as I go into edit mode: reason: 'attempt to insert row 2 into section 0, but there are only 2 rows in section 0 after the update'

Comment: Where? You push `AddProbationerController`, how does it add the new object?

Comment: Isn't if (indexPath.row == self.probationers.count && self.editing)
    {

        AddProbationerController *addProbationer = [[AddProbationerController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:addProbationer animated:YES];
    } supposed to do that? It's just a blank view, and I am not able to actually insert anything yet. But there should not be an error. At least my blank view should show up...

Comment: To begin with, just have the table display the real rows, no fake rows for adding. Use a nav bar button to add new items. Get that working and then go for funky indexing (but probably use a different section with a single row).

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace say it all. Its definitely because of you `self.probationers` array.

Why don't you NSLog the number of items in the array and the number of rows/sections in your tableview.
When you are trying to associate `indexPath.row` and `self.probationers` you have to make sure they match with number of elements.

Also follow the basics while accessing elements of array(as they are much prone to get exceptions)

- Nil check for the accessing array.
- Know the exact count of the array, by logging.
- Make sure you are trying to access any objects more than the available array indexes.